# Google Maps API v3 not working in Firefox

Tags: google-maps-api-3

my Google Maps API v3 installation isn't working on Firefox (V7.0.2), however, it is working perfectly in IE. I guess there is something in the code that Firefox doesn't like.

Can you help me find out?

Thanx.

http://www3.mappeze.de/Lage_und_Anfahrt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, but you didn't see it.

set the display of #map_canvas to "block" instead of "inline".

The settings of width and height doesn't have any effect when the display is set to inline, so you dont see the map.